Create a trail effect in Blender with simulation nodes
I'm trying to create a trail effect in Blender.
I'm trying to create the effect with a simulation node
unfortunately deleting the instances is not working properly
The instances should be deleted after 10 frames
but for some reason Blender only creates instances up to the 10th frame.
As if the delete geometry node was inverted


The newest instance that is joined with the previous ones is always at the same position. It is the previous instances that are transformed at each iteration. So there is nothing wrong with the Delete Geometry node. The oldest instance is deleted, but it is replaced by the previous one. Consequently, the output looks the same.

The newest should be the first of the trail. Meaning the simulation zone should increment the angle and give it to the last added only.
